# How to use `chunk.quietly` in docbook?

Tags: xml, xslt, docbook

I am trying to reduce the verbosity of my XSL transformation, following the documented [chunk.quietly](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/Chunking.html#d0e6157) (and also [here](http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/doc/fo/chunk.quietly.html)). However this is still failing for me:

```
$ /usr/bin/xsltproc  --stringparam chunk.quietly 1 man/gdcmdiff.xml
Note: Writing gdcmdiff.1
```

The [gdcmdiff.xml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/malaterre/GDCM/master/Utilities/doxygen/man/gdcmdiff.xml) is a simple [refentry](http://www.docbook.org/tdg5/en/html/refentry.html) man page:

```
$ head -4 man/gdcmdiff.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl-ns/current/manpages/docbook.xsl" ?>
<refentry xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" version="5.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<info>
```

Comment: Is that actually the complete command-line invocation you’re actually using? Aren’t you also giving `xsltproc` the pathname to a `.xsl` file?

Comment: Also, if a `gdcmdiff.1` file is getting generated, it seems like you must be pointing `xsltproc` to the `docbook-xsl/manpages/docbook.xsl` stylesheet, in which case the `chunk.quietly` param isn’t going to have any effect. But the `man.output.quietly` param will.

Comment: @sideshowbarker did you read the 2nd line of `gdcmdiff.xml` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you’re using the http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl-ns/current/manpages/docbook.xsl stylesheet, for quiet output you need to use the [`man.output.quietly` param](http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/doc/manpages/man.output.quietly.html) (the [`chunk.quietly` param](http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/doc/html/chunk.quietly.html) only affects HTML output).